# Coordinates on Input app

Tags: coordinates, mergin-maps

I am using the Input app for QGIS (V. 3.18).
Is there a way to show the coordinates of my location on the map?

Comment: https://merginmaps.com/docs/field/input_ui/#gps - you can tap on the GPS-accuracy button in order to view this information.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking for a way to represent this information on the map itself. Just like on the Qgis you can see the coordinates as you are hovering with mouse.

Answer (score 0):

This is not implemented, but you can see the GPS coordinates in the GPS Data panel.